# Why is irfftn(rfftn(x)) not equal to x?

Tags: python, numpy, fft

If the trailing dimension of an array `x` is odd, the transform `y = irfftn(rfftn(x))` does not have the same shape as the input array. Is this by design? And if so, what is the motivation? Example code is below.

```
import numpy as np

shapes = [(10, 10), (11, 11), (10, 11), (11, 10)]

for shape in shapes:
    x = np.random.uniform(0, 1, shape)
    y = np.fft.irfftn(np.fft.rfftn(x))
    if x.shape != y.shape:
        print("expected shape %s but got %s" % (shape, y.shape))

# Output
# expected shape (11, 11) but got (11, 10)
# expected shape (10, 11) but got (10, 10)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass second parameter `x.shape`
in your case the code will looks like:

```
import numpy as np

shapes = [(10, 10), (11, 11), (10, 11), (11, 10)]

for shape in shapes:
    x = np.random.uniform(0, 1, shape)
    y = np.fft.irfftn(np.fft.rfftn(x),x.shape)
    if x.shape != y.shape:
        print("expected shape %s but got %s" % (shape, y.shape))
```

from the docs

> This function computes the inverse of the N-dimensional discrete
>   Fourier Transform for real input over any number of axes in an
>   M-dimensional array by means of the Fast Fourier Transform (FFT). In
>   other words, irfftn(rfftn(a), a.shape) == a to within numerical
>   accuracy. (The a.shape is necessary like len(a) is for irfft, and for
>   the same reason.)

x.shape descriptions from the same docs:

> s : sequence of ints, optional Shape (length of each transformed axis)
>   of the output (s[0] refers to axis 0, s[1] to axis 1, etc.). s is also
>   the number of input points used along this axis, except for the last
>   axis, where s[-1]//2+1 points of the input are used. Along any axis,
>   if the shape indicated by s is smaller than that of the input, the
>   input is cropped. If it is larger, the input is padded with zeros. If
>   s is not given, the shape of the input along the axes specified by
>   axes is used.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.irfftn.html